# How to access default color labels in scale_color_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am making a line plot in ggplot2 from [this data](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/blob/master/data/2020/2020-04-28/readme.md). Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
shows <- c('Smile', 'Cats')

smile_week_ending <- grosses_adj %>%
  filter(show == 'Smile') %>%
  pull(week_ending)

grosses %>%
  filter(show %in% shows,
         week_ending %in% smile_week_ending) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week_ending, y = pct_capacity, color = show)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Pretty basic. But I would like to modify the legend to display the "show, seats_in_theatre". I have done this by creating a new variable but this solution feels clumsy.

```
grosses %>%
  filter(show %in% c('Smile', 'Cats'),
         week_ending %in% smile_week_ending) %>%
  mutate(show_seats = paste0(show, ' (', seats_in_theatre, ')')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week_ending, y = pct_capacity, color = show_seats)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Is there a way to modify the label object in [`scale_color_manual`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html) instead of creating a new variable? I have tried reading the documentation for `scale_color_manual` but I don't know how to access the default label variable.

Comment: Are you just wanting `scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Cats (1482)", "Smile (1488)"))`?

Comment: Yes, that works for this example, but I'm wondering if there is a more general, dynamic solution. My actual graph has many more labels. By "default label object" I mean the object that ```ggplot``` creates in the background to use for labels. The documentation  for ```scale_color_manual``` says is uses "```waiver()``` for the default labels computed by the transformation object", but that doesn't actually store the labels.

Comment: At least, when I try to do something like ```scale_color_manual(colors = ..., labels = paste0(waiver(), ...))``` the labels are ```NA```.

Comment: It appears that the ```name``` argument sets the title rather than the labels themselves.

Comment: This might help: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-legend-title-position-and-labels/#rename-legend-labels-and-change-the-order-of-items